# make program restart if user typed smthing wrong and ask user if he wants to restart the game

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

> This is the code i am currently running

```
from random import randint
print("Rock,Paper or Scissors?")
choice=input()
r=["Rock" , "Paper" , "Scissors"]
comp=r[randint(0,2)]
```

> I have tried to change the lo to False or to True , but still can't figure it out

```
lo = True
while lo==True :
    if comp == choice:
        print("Tie!")
    elif comp == "Rock":
        if choice == "Paper":
            print("You won, " + choice + " covers " + comp )
        elif choice == "Scissors":
            print("You lost, " + comp + " breaks " + choice )
    elif comp == "Scissors":
        if choice == "Rock":
            print("You won, " + choice + " breaks " + comp )
        elif choice == "Paper":
            print("You lost, " + comp + " cuts " + choice)
    elif comp == "Paper":
        if choice == "Rock":
            print("You won, " + choice + " covers " + comp )
        elif choice == "Scissors":
            print("You won, " + choice + " cuts " + comp )
    else:
        print("You have entered something wrong please re-enter your choice")
print("Do you want to play again. Yes or No?")
answ=input()
if answ=="Yes":
    lo=True
    print("Choose between Rock,Paper and Scissors again")
    choice=input()
elif answ=="No":
    lo=False
    print("Goodbye!")
```

> Also i don't know why , the output is just an indefinite loop

[Example](https://prnt.sc/si97w0)

Comment: Hint: what needs to happen to `lo` in order for the loop to exit? Can that happen while the loop is running? How?

Comment: maybe lo=False?

Comment: Okay, and what causes `lo` to become `False`? Where in your code is that? Can you see why that doesn't actually allow the loop to stop?

Comment: `answ=input()` and statements below it move  inside the while loop

Comment: lo becomes false only when the user enters no?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/si9n7x now the user can restart the game if he wants to

Comment: https://prnt.sc/si9obo :( cant seem to figure out how to restart the game if user enters smthing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an infinite loop because you don't change lo
The question is out of the while loop
This a possible fix:

```
from random import randint

lo = True
while lo==True :
    err=False
    print("Rock,Paper or Scissors?")
    r=["Rock" , "Paper" , "Scissors"]
    comp=r[randint(0,2)]
    choice=input()
    if comp == choice:
        print("Tie!")
        lo=False
    elif comp == "Rock":
        if choice == "Paper":
            print("You won, " + choice + " covers " + comp )
        elif choice == "Scissors":
            print("You lost, " + comp + " breaks " + choice )
        lo=False
    elif comp == "Scissors":
        if choice == "Rock":
            print("You won, " + choice + " breaks " + comp )
        elif choice == "Paper":
            print("You lost, " + comp + " cuts " + choice)
        lo=False
    elif comp == "Paper":
        if choice == "Rock":
            print("You won, " + choice + " covers " + comp )
        elif choice == "Scissors":
            print("You won, " + choice + " cuts " + comp )
        lo=False
    else:
        print("You have entered something wrong please re-enter your choice")
        err=True
    if(not err):
        print("Do you want to play again. Yes or No?")
        answ=input()
        if answ=="Yes":
            lo=True
        elif answ=="No":
            lo=False
        else:
            lo=False
```

Comment: just so i can understand , why did you put the err ? Plus this is what happens when i run it https://prnt.sc/si9sqo

Comment: I need to fix that, if the if then else got to the else option (no correct option selected) then its an error and you start again. but it doesn't get there even if enter g instead of Scissors, that's a bug need fixing